# Multiple nested forms in Rails with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I am a Rails newbie creating a clone of the dating site OkCupid as an exercise. I am working on the form to display a Question, its possible Answers, and its possible SoughtAnswers (which are Answers that the User selects to indicate how s/he wants other Users to answer the same Question).

**Example data:**

Question: "How many children do you have?"

Answer: "2" (other possible Answers include "0", "1", and "3+")

SoughtAnswers: "0","1","2"

**Problem:**

I am using the simple_form gem to create the form to collect the User's responses to a Question. I'm lost on how to display the form correctly and create a new AnsweredQuestion, which stores a User, Question, Answer, and SoughtAnswers for one complete response to a Question.

How should I change my models and form to properly create an AnsweredQuestion?

Here are excerpted parts of relevant files:

**question.rb**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :body, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_many :answers, inverse_of: :question, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :answered_questions, inverse_of: :question, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sought_answers, through: :answers, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, reject_if: :all_blank
```

**answer.rb**

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question, inverse_of: :answers
  has_many :answered_questions, inverse_of: :answer, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sought_answers, dependent: :destroy
```

**sought_answer.rb**

```
class SoughtAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, through: :answered_question
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :answered_question, inverse_of: :sought_answers
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answered_questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questions, through: :answered_questions
  has_many :sought_answers, dependent: :destroy
```

**answered_question.rb**

```
class AnsweredQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer
  has_many :sought_answers, inverse_of: :answered_question, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sought_answers, reject_if: :all_blank
```

**AnsweredQuestionsController**:

```
  def create
    @answered_question = AnsweredQuestion.new(answered_question_params)
    @answered_question.user = current_user
    @answered_question.sought_answers.each do |sa|
      sa.answered_question = @answered_question
    end

  private
    def answered_question_params
      params.require(:answered_question).permit(:question_id, :answer_id, sought_answers_attributes: [:answer_id])
    end
```

**answered_questions/_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= simple_form_for @answered_question do |aq_form| %>
  <%= aq_form.input :question_id, as: :hidden %>
  <%= @answered_question.question.body %>

  <%= aq_form.simple_fields_for @answered_question.question.answers do |answer_fields| %>
    <%= answer_fields.input :body %>
  <% end %>

  <div class='sought-answer-header'>
    People I'm most interested in would answer:
  </div>

  <%= aq_form.simple_fields_for @answered_question.sought_answers do |sa_fields| %>
    <%= sa_fields.input :answer, label_method: :body, value_method: :id, include_blank: :false, label_html: { class: 'sought-answer-body' } %>
  <% end %>

  <%= aq_form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

**dashboard_controller.rb**

```
  def show
    @answered_question = AnsweredQuestion.new
    @answered_question.user = current_user
    @answered_question.question = current_user.random_unanswered_question
    @answered_question.question.answers.each do |answer|
      @answered_question.sought_answers.build(answer: answer)
    end
  end
```

The form currently returns this error:

```
NoMethodError in Dashboard#show

undefined method `has_attribute?' for #<Answer::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fd7ee8124f0>
Extracted source (around line #21):

    <%= answer_fields.input :body %>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Hello Mark, can you post contents of the 'new' method in AnsweredQuestionsController?

Comment: Hey @lavilet, I've added the DashboardController#show method that is called before the form is loaded. Thanks for any help you can offer!